# Twenty Thirteen and sidebar overflows footer - Top Margin

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, sidebar

I have been trying to stop the sidebar from overflowing the footer in a child theme from Twenty Thirteen in Wordpress 4.0.

I added the following CSS code that I found in another post on another site.

**CSS:**

```
/* Fix Sidebar Overlaping Footer*/

.sidebar .entry-header, .sidebar .entry-content, .sidebar .entry-summary, .sidebar .entry-meta {
   padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
   max-width: 100%;
}

.sidebar .site-footer .widget-area {
    max-width: 1040px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-top:10px!important;
}

.hentry {
   padding: 20px 0px;
}

@media (min-width: 999px) {

   #main {
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0px auto;
      max-width: 1080px;
   } 

   #primary.content-area {
      width: 68%;
      float: left;
   }

   .site-main .sidebar-container {
      position: static;
      float: right;
      width: 30%;
      height: auto;
   }
   .site-main .widget-area {
      margin-top: 24px;
      margin-right: 20px;
   }

}
```

The problem is that there is javascript (functions.js in twentythirteen/js) that is adding a huge top-margin to the footer which you can see the results of here: http://tcsdesignreno.com/addnv/

**Javascript:**

```
/**
     * Adds a top margin to the footer if the sidebar widget area is higher
     * than the rest of the page, to help the footer always visually clear
     * the sidebar.
     */
    $( function() {
        if ( body.is( '.sidebar' ) ) {
            var sidebar   = $( '#secondary .widget-area' ),
                secondary = ( 0 === sidebar.length ) ? -40 : sidebar.height(),
                margin    = $( '#tertiary .widget-area' ).height() - $( '#content' ).height() - secondary;

            if ( margin > 0 && _window.innerWidth() > 999 ) {
                $( '#colophon' ).css( 'margin-top', margin + 'px' );
            }
        }
    } );
```

Does anyone have a solution that works to stop the sidebar from overlapping the footer or to stop the js from adding the top margin? I know I have done this before but I can't seem to find the correct combination of code.

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

Well, in essence you answered the question for me.

The line in the .js that creates the css for the margin top has the ID #colophon

I added this line to my child theme css and it takes care of the margin-top:

> #colophon {margin-top:0 !important;}

Comment: This does not answer the question